# Encountering a connectino exception while starting JBoss server

Tags: jboss, redhat

I am running JBoss server in redhat OS....while starting the server i get a connection time out error....the following is the log of the jboss server...

```
17/05 14:40:41:752 INFO [ ] AjpProtocol start() Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-10.0.4.62-8009
17/05 14:40:41:763 INFO [ ] Server doStart() JBoss (MX MicroKernel) [4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)] Started in 26s:130ms
[Loaded com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryResourceImple from file:/jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/lib/jbossjta.jar]
[Loaded java.io.NotSerializableException from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
17/05 14:40:57:966 WARN [ ] SocketManager logger() Exception caught in SocketManager::createAndPutSockets::e = java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
17/05 14:40:57:968 WARN [ ] SocketManager logger() CreateAndPutSockets ::Exiting with availableSockets= [] busySockets= []
17/05 14:40:57:968 WARN [ ] SocketManager logger() CreateAndPutSockets ::No connection established.Returning false to calling function
17/05 14:40:57:968 WARN [ ] SocketChannelManager logger() Exception caught in SocketManager::createAndPutSocketChannels::e = java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
17/05 14:40:57:968 WARN [ ] SocketChannelManager logger() CreateAndPutSocketChannels ::Exiting with availableSocketChannels= [] busySocketChannels= []
17/05 14:40:57:969 WARN [ ] SocketChannelManager logger() CreateAndPutSockets ::No connection established.Returning false to calling function
```

Comment: please help.........!!

Comment: How is your firewall set up? what about `netstat -antpl`?

Comment: thanks....i had some problem with firewall i guess...